# how to loop through TextView variables in android

Tags: java, android, for-loop, textview

I am very new to Android, and If any errors exists please notify me. I have this code in one of my `java` file

```
String temp1=tvLecTime1.getText().toString();
String temp2=tvLecTime2.getText().toString();
String temp3=tvLecTime3.getText().toString();
String temp4=tvLecTime4.getText().toString();
String temp5=tvLecTime5.getText().toString();
String temp[]={"null",temp1,temp2,temp3,temp4,temp5};

for(int i=1;i<6;i++){

    lecTime=temp[i];
    requestServerForTimeTable.fetchLectureDataInBackgroundEditTimeTable(
           day, year, lecTime,
           new GetLectureCallBack() {

                @Override
                public void done(LectureDetails lectureDetailsReturned) {

                    lectureLocalDatabase.storeData(lectureDetailsReturned);
                    LectureDetails lectureDetailsReceivedFromSP = 
                                          lectureLocalDatabase.getDataBack();
                    tvLecture1.setText(lectureDetailsReceivedFromSP.courseId);
                    tvHall1.setText(lectureDetailsReceivedFromSP.hall);

                }
          });
}
```

`GetLectureCallBack` is an interface and `lectureLocalDatabase.getDataBack()` returns an `LectureDetails` object. as the values for `lecTime` changes throughout the `for loop` the values for `courseId` and `hall` variables are also changed. there are 10 TextViews from `tvLecture1` upto `tvLecture5` and `tvHall1` upto `tvHall5`. I need to assign first `courseId` and `hall` values to `tvLecture1` and `tvHall1` respectively and second values to `tvLecture2` and `tvHall2` and so on. So how make the `TextView` variables get looped in the same for loop. Thanks in advance

Comment: you can make array of `TextView` for `tvHall` and `tvLecture` or you can use ListView with custom adapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have two Array holding the `TextView` objects and then loop over them.

The catch is your `i` variable is a local variable and therefore cannot be accessed inside the Anonymous Method unless it is defined as `final` (which you cannot do since you need to increment it). The solution would be to pass it to a new variable who is final:

```
String temp1=tvLecTime1.getText().toString();
String temp2=tvLecTime2.getText().toString();
String temp3=tvLecTime3.getText().toString();
String temp4=tvLecTime4.getText().toString();
String temp5=tvLecTime5.getText().toString();
String temp[]={temp1,temp2,temp3,temp4,temp5};

TextView[] tcLectures = { tvLecture1, tvLecture2, tvLecture3, tvLecture4, tvLecture5 };
TextView[] tvHalls = { tvHall1, tvHall2, tvHall3, tvHall4, tvHall5 };

for(int i=0; i<5; i++){

    lecTime=temp[i];
    final currentIndex = i;

    requestServerForTimeTable.fetchLectureDataInBackgroundEditTimeTable(
           day, year, lecTime,
           new GetLectureCallBack() {

                @Override
                public void done(LectureDetails lectureDetailsReturned) {

                    lectureLocalDatabase.storeData(lectureDetailsReturned);
                    LectureDetails lectureDetailsReceivedFromSP = 
                                          lectureLocalDatabase.getDataBack();
                    tcLectures[currentIndex].setText(
                              lectureDetailsReceivedFromSP.courseId);
                    tvHalls[currentIndex].setText(
                              lectureDetailsReceivedFromSP.hall);

                }
          });
}
```

Comment: I'll test it and let you know the how it went as soon as possible, right now I am fixing a bug that arose before running of this code :(

Answer (score 2):

It's bad practice using loop of **TextView** to display array of some information.
Much better use **ListView** or **RecyclerView**:

You can find more information on offical site or Internet.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html
https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
TextView[] tvLectViews = {tvLecture1, tvLecture2, tvLecture3, tvLecture4, tvLecture5};
TextView[] tvHallViews = {tvHall1, tvHall2, tvHall3, tvHall4, tvHall5};
```

now you can easily iterate through the array